# consulta msyql agrupando datos

Tags: mysql, sql

buen dia a todo el foro de stackeoverflow estoy empezando mas en serio la programacion tengo la siguiente tabla en mysql, quisiera realizar una consulta en la cual por ejemplo los datos se agrupen asi. por ejemplo

de la columna resp, hay 25 registros con codigo 1, hay 10 registros con codigo 2 y asi sucesivamente he intentado usar sum pero no me lo muestra de esa forma alguna sugerencia por favor.

[image: tabla mysql]

Comment: Saludos. En vez de `SUM` usa `COUNT`; te falto colocar tu actual SQL para en dado caso indicarte la corrección específica.

Comment: Con Group By y el campo.

Comment: Por favor pon lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar

Comment: Grindor, debes mostrar que intentos de consulta has hecho, para saber que es lo que entiendes, y que no

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a agrupar por el campo resp, y utilizar COUNT(*).

```html
SELECT resp, COUNT(*) AS veces
FROM table
GROUP BY resp
```

Comment: Las preguntas donde el op no demuestra esfuerzo no se responden, en este caso el op debió poner el código que había intentado

Comment: Ok. No lo había tenido en cuenta.